# PC rapidly turning off and on

Tags: computer-building

So I just bought a bunch of components for my computer:

- Ryzen 3 2200G
- HyperX 8GB 2666MHz
- AsRock AB350M motherboard

I installed it in my old case, but when I plug it in (Not even touching the power button) it starts rapidly turning off and on. Is it a bad component? It shouldn't be underpowered, since I looked at that. Something that did catch my eye was the fact that the motherboard used an 8 pin connector, but my psu uses a 4 pin connector. According to the manual this is supposed to work. The power button is probably not the problem, since it even does this when the power button is not connected to the motherboard. Diagnostics:

- SD card reader lights flash
- CPU fan starts spinning
- RGB mouse flashes
- Keyboard lights flash
- Happens about twice a second, even when the power button isn't pressed or even connected. Its happens as soon as I turn on the power supply.

Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm on mobile.

Comment: How are we supposed to know anything about what you have and what you did?

Comment: what does "_rapid_" mean...?

Comment: I didn't calculate it or anything, but its like twice a second

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the retailer, and apparently this has happened before. The BIOS software is simply outdated and doesn't recognize the brand new CPU. I am still wondering why it turned on without me touching the powerbutton.

Answer (score 0):

First reseat everything also make sure your cables for the power button is in the right spot should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiV12.jpg)
I believe it could be plugged in the wrong spot
The pin it plugs into should be labeled next to the pins like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BE7w.jpg)
I would say somthing isnt seated correctly or these pins are in the wrong spot

Sorry for bad formatting on mobile :(

Comment: I tried it with the powerbutton unplugged, but it still failed

Comment: [This guy](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/computer-rapidly-turns-itself-on-and-off-362029/) had the same issue i would try clearing the cmos and try flashing the bios if it gives you the chance